# Getting right product bij combining results from 3 tables (Union or JOIN)

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so I'll try to give as much information as possible. I've spent couple of hours trying to figure it out but all the examples I see doesn't help me.

I have 3 tables and I must retrieve the products name from table 3 (products) where the status of table 1 (orders) is 0. This is easy part but in table 2 (orders) I find only `order_id` and in table 2 (order_amount) I can see the `product_id`, this I need to get the right product name.

```
table1: orders
      id    
      date  
      recipient     
      country   
      city   
      street    
      payment_method    
      email     
      status    
      transaction_id       
      options_price

table2: order_amount
      id 
      order_id  
      product_id    
      color_id  
      amount    
      options

table3: products
      id    
      name
      description   
      price     
      shipment_fee  
      stock     
      conditie
```

I hope someone can help me as I find it hard to work with `JOIN` and `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` with order_amount should be good enough.

```
SELECT name FROM Products P
LEFT JOIN order_amount AM
on P.id = AM.product_id
where AM.product_id is NULL
```

Comment: uhm i don't understand it but i tried and got this in return: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: maybe the rest is wrong for this to work, i have this now:  $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM Products P LEFT JOIN order_amount AM on P.id = AM.product_id where AM.product_id is NULL");  and then this: $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH) and finaly: $row["name"]

Answer (score 0):

ok i found this solution

```
$result = mysql_query   (" SELECT name FROM products P 
                        LEFT JOIN order_amount AM on P.id = AM.product_id 
                        LEFT JOIN orders O on AM.order_id = O.id 
                        WHERE O.status = 0 order by date desc");
```

(tnx to radar for boosting my direction)

but now i have a second problem, i have 2 while loops

while (   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
while (   $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))

this ofcource doesn't work but how do you handle this?
because the outcome is on 1 line

Comment: i got it to work (still tnx to radar's comment) but i used <table> so little old school but it works.